# Is there a name for this type of diagram?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, synthetic-biology, genetic-diagrams

Is there any commonly used name for this type of diagram / symbology? I have not been able to find them referred to by any name.

[image]

Comment: is this what you are looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_diagram

Comment: The glyphs themselves come from SBOL visual: https://sbolstandard.org/visual-glyphs/. You could look in the spec to see if they refer to the diagrams as something other than an SBOL visual diagram.